# Apache config: allow iFrames only for a specific directory

Tags: apache2

I would like to configure Apache so that

- it normally denies requests for iFrames (for instance, by setting `Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY`)
- **but**, it allows a specific directory to be embedded as iFrame, independently from the origin of the request (for instance, `<iframe src="www.mysite.com/mydir"></iframe>`)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See documentation for [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options). You can

- allow embedding **from** `https://example.com/mydir`:

  ```
  Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=https://example.com/mydir
  ```
- allow embedding **of** `https://example.com/mydir` 
   by adding it only when `Location` doesn't match `/mydir`, with the [`LocationMatch` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch).

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com

      <LocationMatch "^/(?!mydir)(.*)">
          Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
      </LocationMatch>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- to maximize security, add a combination of these i.e. only allow embedding of `/mydir` from `...`.

You can't limit it to `<iframe>` alone, but the embedding can also be done as `<frame>` or `<object>`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I only had to invert the regexp match (my original request was to deny everything that is not under `/mydir`).

Comment: My mistake! Now it should have correct negation, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, with my edit it works fine :)

Comment: Uh, I see now that you rejected my edit. I had also corrected the wrong closing tag to `</LocationMatch>`.

Comment: I didn't reject it, but when using the App I may have overwritten it with my own modification. Sorry. Edited the closing tag again.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it works only if i do like this

```
    <LocationMatch "^/mydir(.*)">
       Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
    </LocationMatch>
```

in order to allow the `/mydir` folder...

EDIT:
forget about what i said, this setting doesn't block anything

Answer (score 0):

For me I would have updated the modsecurity files:

File: etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-security.conf

```
     SecRule REQUEST_URI|REMOTE_HOST "@contains /directorytotarget" "phase:2,nolog,setenv:sameoriginonly,t:none,t:urlDecode,t:normalizePath,t:lowercase,pass,msg:'setting X-Frame-Options'"
     Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" env=sameoriginonly
```